# Geocoded_Waypoints Google Maps Api Zero Results

Tags: python, json, api, google-maps, request

I am using google maps api with this python code to print a route between two points.

```
import requests, json
#Google MapsDdirections API endpoint
endpoint = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?'
api_key = 'AIzaSyCTPkufBttRcfSkA9zPYgivrYs9QEhdEEU'
#Asks the user to input Where they are and where they want to go.
origin = input('Where are you?: ').replace(' ','+')
destination = input('Where do you want to go?: ').replace(' ','+')
#Building the URL for the request
nav_request = 'origin={}&destination={}&key={}'.format(origin,destination,api_key)
request = endpoint + nav_request
#Sends the request and reads the response.
#response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
r = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Vigo&destination=Lugo&key=AIzaSyCTPkufBttRcfSkA9zPYgivrYs9QEhdEEU')
#Loads response as JSON
#directions = json.loads(response)
directions = r.json()
print(directions)
```

The problem is that my response gives me ZERO_RESULTS.
I´ve tried it manually in google chrome getting the next result:

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJbYcwsYDOMQ0RDAVnKL9fMB8",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJk8GyYRRiLw0Rn9RLF60dRHs",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 43.0082848,
               "lng" : -7.554997200000001
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 42.2392374,
               "lng" : -8.720694999999999
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Datos de mapas ©2019 Inst. Geogr. Nacional",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "188 km",
                  "value" : 188311
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2h 11 min",
                  "value" : 7830
               },
               "end_address" : "Vigo, Pontevedra, España",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 42.2406168,
                  "lng" : -8.720694999999999
               },
               "start_address" : "Lugo, España",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 43.0082848,
[...]
```

However, when I try it online i get different geocoded waypoints and, therefore, zero_results.

```
'types': ['bar', 'establishment', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'restaurant']}], 'routes': [], 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'}
```

How can I change geocoded_waypoint types??

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your example you try to get directions between two Spanish cities. However, when you specify only names of cities in origin and destination the service might resolve them to different countries due to ambiguity in parameters. For example, when I execute your request on my server that located in USA the destination Lugo is resolved to place ID `ChIJi59iTw6wZIgRvssCUK9Ra84` which is a restaurant with name "Lugo's" located in 107 S Main St, Dickson, TN 37055, USA.

See place details

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJi59iTw6wZIgRvssCUK9Ra84&fields=formatted_address,geometry,name,type&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

As origin is located in Spain and destination in USA, the directions service cannot build a driving directions and returns ZERO_RESULTS.

In order to resolve ambiguity you should provide more precise origin and destination parameters or specify a region where you are searching results.

If I add `region` parameter in request I get expected route between Spanish cities

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Vigo&destination=Lugo&region=ES&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

You can see it in directions calculator:

https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/?origin=Vigo&destination=Lugo&region=ES

I hope my answer clarifies your doubt!